# Testing an api through a GUI for client

Tags: api, testing

My boss wants a GUI based api request sender - He initially asked for something already out there (so I don't have to build anything)

Anyone know of an online resource or tool that will allow you to, say, send 1000 requests over 10 minutes?

Comment: Are you asking about a web based API, or some other type of API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a web based API, take a look at Apache JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Comment: Yes, this is a web based api. This will be a very simple test to measure success of the request, how long each request took, and an average time for all requests.

Comment: Marked as correct because I didn't find anything else, and this does look as though it would provide the necessary functionality. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

soundcloud has a nice api console using apigee. http://developers.soundcloud.com/console